# terraform - Iterate over two linked resources

Tags: terraform

I’m trying to write some code which would take an input structure like this:

```
  projects = {
    "project1" = {
      namespaces = ["mynamespace1"]
     },
    "project2" = {
      namespaces = ["mynamespace2", "mynamespace3"]
    }
  }
```

and provision multiple resources with for_each which would result in this:

```
resource "rancher2_project" "project1" {
  provider   = rancher2.admin
  cluster_id = module.k8s_cluster.cluster_id

  wait_for_cluster = true
}

resource "rancher2_project" "project2" {
  provider   = rancher2.admin
  cluster_id = module.k8s_cluster.cluster_id

  wait_for_cluster = true
}

resource "rancher2_namespace" "mynamespace1" {
  provider    = rancher2.admin
    project_id  = rancher2_project.project1.id
   
  depends_on = [rancher2_project.project1]
}

resource "rancher2_namespace" "mynamespace2" {
  provider    = rancher2.admin
    project_id  = rancher2_project.project2.id
   
  depends_on = [rancher2_project.project2]
}

resource "rancher2_namespace" "mynamespace3" {
  provider    = rancher2.admin
    project_id  = rancher2_project.project2.id
   
  depends_on = [rancher2_project.project2]
}
```

namespaces are dependent on Projects and the generate id needs to be passed into namespace.

Is there any good way of doing this dynamically ? We might have a lot of Projects/namespaces.

Thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: Your example isn't iterating over 2 provider configurations and instead is over 2 resources that use the same provider but different projects. Are you missing something in your example?

Comment: My bad should be over 2 resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical answer for systematically generating multiple instances of a resource based on a data structure is [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings). The main requirement for resource `for_each` is to have a map which contains one element per resource instance you want to create.

In your case it seems like you need one `rancher2_project` per project and then one `rancher2_namespace` for each pair of project and namespaces. Your current data structure is therefore already sufficient for the `rancher2_project` resource:

```
resource "rancher2_project" "example" {
  for_each = var.projects
  provider = rancher2.admin

  cluster_id       = module.k8s_cluster.cluster_id
  wait_for_cluster = true
}
```

The above will declare two resource instances with the following addresses:

- `rancher2_project.example["project1"]`
- `rancher2_project.example["project2"]`

You don't currently have a map that has one element per *namespace*, so it will take some more work to derive a suitable value from your input data structure. A common pattern for this situation is [flattening nested structures for `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each) using [the `flatten` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html):

```
locals {
  project_namespaces = flatten([
    for pk, proj in var.projects : [
      for nsk in proj.namespaces : {
        project_key   = pk
        namespace_key = ns
        project_id    = rancher2_project.example[pk].id
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "rancher2_namespace" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for obj in local.project_namespaces :
    "${obj.project_key}.${obj.namespace_key}" => obj
  }
  provider = rancher2.admin

  project_id = each.value.project_id
}
```

This produces a list of objects representing all of the project and namespace pairs, and then the `for_each` argument transforms it into a map using compound keys that include both the project and namespace keys to ensure that they will all be unique. The resulting instances will therefore have the following addresses:

- `rancher2_namespace.example["project1.mynamespace1"]`
- `rancher2_namespace.example["project2.mynamespace2"]`
- `rancher2_namespace.example["project2.mynamespace3"]`

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation, I looked at the flatten function but didn't understand how to use it in the namespace resource. A for in an for_each .. (0-0)

Comment: I was able to do the namespace with using count and something like this: 
local.project_namespaces[count.index].namespace_name, this way you don't need to do another conversion from list to map. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work too:

```
resource "rancher2_namespace" "example" {
  count      = length(local.project_namespaces)
  provider   = rancher2.admin
  name       = local.project_namespaces[count.index].namespace_name
  project_id = local.project_namespaces[count.index].project_id
}
```